# instructors, who are all?

Tags: grammar

What does the relative pronoun "who" here refer to? why ?

1. instructors ?
2. course masters and instructors ?

*Much time is dedicated to interactive and practical training under the supervision of course masters and instructors, **who** are all internationally recognized European or American specialists*.

Comment: *NASA trainees consist of men and women who are tops in their respective fields*. The men are vagabonds dragged in off the street; it is only the women who are tops in their fields.

Comment: Because you've got your comma AFTER ***course masters and instructors***, it's obvious they're being treated as a "collective" entity modified by the following ***wh-*** clause. If that final clause only applied to ***instructors***, at the very least you'd have to remove the comma. OR, to avoid *any* potential ambiguity, put the comma after ***masters***. That prevents the scope of the ***wh-*** clause from extending back to include ***course masters***  as well as ***instructors***.

Answer (score 4):

Because *course masters and instructors* are mentioned together, the description almost certainly refers to both groups.

If it was intended to refer only to the instructors, I would expect the two to be separated in some way -

> ...under the supervision of course masters, and of instructors who are all recognized...

Comment: And simple logic tells us that if instructors are well-recognized, so are course **masters**.

Comment: @KateBunting Is '' course masters and instructors '' a noun phrase? There is a conjunction '' and '' in between. because the relative pronoun replaces the noun or noun phrase?

Comment: No, because it contains _two_ nouns.

Comment: A coordination of two noun phrases can be regarded as a (larger) noun phrase.